# How to hide navigation drawer `menuitems` when particular fragment is selected?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Here is Login fragment :

```
public class Login extends Fragment {

    TextInputEditText u_name,u_pass;
    String name_user,password_user;
    Button login_btn;
    TextView user_register;
    String PREF="myData";
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    NavigationView navigationView;


    public Login() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        u_name=(TextInputEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        u_pass=(TextInputEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.user_password);
        login_btn=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
        user_register=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.register_user);

        //setting up navigationview text and image

        navigationView=(NavigationView) view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                name_user=u_name.getText().toString().trim();
                password_user=u_pass.getText().toString();

                if (name_user.isEmpty())
                {
                    u_name.setError("Enter email address");
                }
                else if (password_user.isEmpty())
                {
                    u_pass.setError("Enter password");
                }
                else
                {
                    loginUser();
                }

            }
        });

        user_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new RegisterUser()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private void loginUser()
    {
        final ProgressDialog pd=ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Login","Please wait",false);
        StringRequest loginRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://mywebdata.com/webservice/logincheck.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                pd.dismiss();
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (response.contains("Invalid Email Address and Password"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid Email Address and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    getLoginUser(response);
                }


                //Log.e("login",""+response);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                pd.dismiss();
                Log.e("Error",""+error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network error please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("usrname",name_user);
                map.put("passwrd",password_user);
                return map;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        queue.add(loginRequest);
    }

    private void getLoginUser(String user)
    {
        ParseJson parseJson=new ParseJson(user);
        parseJson.parseUserLogin();

        if (ParseJson.login_mail[0].equals(name_user))
        {
            preferences=getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor=preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("LOGIN_USER",ParseJson.login_id[0]);
            editor.putString("LOGIN NAME",ParseJson.login_name[0]);
            editor.commit();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid user name,Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

problem is that when is call   `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`it gives me error that i can not call this witihn fragment Login.I tried many SO answer but that not work in my case all of them are working fine with Activity but not within Fragment.

Thanks for your time...

Comment: You must implement NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener in your Login Fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fragment has no implemented `'NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener'` when you do

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

so do this

```
public class Login extends Fragment implements
                                    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

and override the methods and you are good to go

Update : To hide and show `menuitems` in `navigationView` when specific fragment selected

1.) Initialize the `navigationView` in your activity

2.) Inside navigation listener

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

   @Override
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
      if(menuItem.getItemId()==R.id.login_fragment )  {
           // to hide items  
          navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.item_to_hide).setVisible(false);
           //  to show items
          navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.item_to_show).setVisible(true);
   }   
      return true;
   }
});
```

where `getMenu()` gives you menu object

`findItem(id)` gives you the `menuitem` to hide/show

`setVisibile()` will modify the state of `menuitem` to visible/invisible

Comment: it give me another error that **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference**

Comment: mean your `navigationView` is not initialized properly. check your `fragment_login` layout should have a` navigationView` with this `nav_view` id

Comment: View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false); navigationView=(NavigationView) view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view); My MainActivity have navigationview and i set username to the text of navigationview in my login_fragment

Comment: post your fragment_login XML in your question

Comment: i think the navigation view is in your activity xml and u r trying to get an instance in fragment

Comment: i got it , you don't have navigation view in your fragment so you can't initialize it your fragment , do this in your activity or put your navigation view  XML code in `fragment_login `

Comment: Yes i want visible some menu item from login fragment @darwin

Comment: You must put the code related to navigation view in your activity,and add functions to change visibility of menu items in activity and call from fragment

Comment: can u plz provide some example for that...thanks @darwin

Comment: before that, do you want to show or hide some menu items on some changes in Login fragment.is it?

Comment: yes i want to show and hide two menu item that is depend upon login fragment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123582/discussion-between-manish-yadav-and-darwin).

Answer (score 2):

Implement below interface in `fragment/activity`:

```
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

Add following code inside `oncreate/oncreateView`

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```